# Form validation Regex to get rid of lowercase characters

Tags: jquery, regex, webforms

Trying to get a class change when entering any character other than lowercase letters in a text box. However, and I am sure that there is some stupid little thing causing this, its is not showing console.log of "yo!". Here is the javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name='name']").keyup(function(){
        var str = $(this).val();
        var badChars = new RegExp("[^a-z]");
        if (str.indexOf(badChars)!=-1){
            console.log("yo!");
            $(this).removeClass("good");
            $(this).addClass("error");
        }
    });
});
```

What am I messing up?

Comment: Is it better to use name or ID?

Comment: str.indexOf takes a **string** and not a regular expression. You probably want **match** or **test**. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    // Don't need to create new RegExp object on each keyup event.
    // Just create it once:
    var badChars = new RegExp("[^a-z]");

    $("input[name='name']").keyup(function() {
        // Use RegExp.test() method to check 
        // is string matches the regular expression.
        if (badChars.test(this.value)) {
            console.log("yo!");
            $(this).removeClass("good")
                   .addClass("error");
        }
    });
});
```

[`RegExp.test()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)